# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3509 to array axis with dimension 6

Tags: python, pandas, oop, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit my data to a logistic regressor and I get this error.

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        self.X_train = X_train,
        self.y_train = y_train,
        self.X_test = X_test,
        self.y_test = y_test

    def train(self):
        X_train = self.X_train
        y_train = self.y_train
        clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`X_train` and `y _train` is of type tuple. this happens in the `__init__` method, so I am guessing it is the default behavior.
I am very new to writing OOP code so I am sure there are better ways to accomplish this and it is possible that the error is because of data passed between classes.

EDIT: This works when I place "clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)" directly in main method

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Where is your error?
And also please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding commas to those statements in `__init__`, you're creating tuples:

```
t = X_train,
type(t)
# tuple
```

Also, the point of setting all variables as class attributes in the initialization, is so they can be shared across the class methods, so the `X_train = self.X_train` assignment makes no sense. So you should be doing:

```
class Train():
    def __init__(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_test = y_test
        
    def train(self):
        self.cls = LogisticRegression() 
        self.cls.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
```

As a final note, I'm guessing that your class contains some additional logic other than what it contains right now. Otherwise it doesn't make sense, `LogisticRegression` is already a class with a `fit` method.